# layout_below doesn't place text underneath

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout, android-relativelayout, android-cardview

*Hello, I tried to copy the Code of a tutorial, but it doesn't work out for me... The Layout_below won't move the text to underneath the picture, can somebody help?*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
    app:cardElevation="7dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgFood"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMealName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imgFood"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:text="@string/meal_name"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: You are missing the closing tag `</RelativeLayout>`  Where the `RelativeLayout` should wrap the `ImageView` and `TextView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your text view and image view are not inside RelativeLayout
replace below code with your code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
    app:cardElevation="7dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/imgFood"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:contentDescription="some text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMealName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/imgFood"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:text="cheese pizza "
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

close Relative layout using `</RelativeLayout>`  after Textview